# How to Display a Blank Data at an Unexisting Empty `<td>` Element in a Table

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I think this question is easy... I want this HTML code of a table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Heading 1</th>
    <td>or</td>
    <th>Heading 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data 1 of Row 2</td>
    <td>Data 2 of Row 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data 1 of Row 3</td>
    <td>Data 2 of Row 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

To produce an output as:

[image: Table with Empty <td> Elements]

AND NOT as:

[image: Table without Empty <td> Elements]

In other words, I want to show it as:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Heading 1</th>
    <td>or</td>
    <th>Heading 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data 1 of Row 2</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Data 2 of Row 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data 1 of Row 3</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Data 2 of Row 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Even there's no empty `<td>` elements on my code.. I really didn't want to write a `<td>` element in a table when it has an empty content.. What attribute *(with value)* should I use? Should it be `style` attribute? *(I hope it's not!)* Is this possible?

Comment: you can use colspan =2 on your first td. that way you don't have to add blank td and presentation will look good

Comment: @swapneel But there's no blank table data with that attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Is the word "or" really important content, or just decoration? Looks kind of odd to me. Here's a cheeky alternative:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">
th {position: relative;}
th:first-child:after {
    content: "or";
    position: relative;
    right: -1em;
    top: 0;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Heading 1</th>
    <th>Heading 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data 1 of Row 2</td>
    <td>Data 2 of Row 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data 1 of Row 3</td>
    <td>Data 2 of Row 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

*warning* Not tested in IE.

Comment: I see.. It's quite awesome! But STILL, it's a little bit of tricky.

Answer (score 0):

#### I told 'ya, IT'S EASY..

After just using the *so called* opposite attribute of `colspan`, named *(attribute)* `rowspan` and searching a little bit, and using the alternative supported CSS for unsupported `valign` attribute in HTML5, this is what I've found:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Heading 1</th>
    <td rowspan="3" style="vertical-align: text-top;">or</td>
    <th>Heading 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data 1 of Row 2</td>
    <td>Data 2 of Row 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data 1 of Row 3</td>
    <td>Data 2 of Row 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Test it on any HTML*(5)* interpreter and see that the output of this HTML code is looks like as:

[image: The Wanted Table in the Question]

Even without empty `<td>` elements in the table. BUT STILL, I wondered if someone knew how to markup a table with the construction like this:

```
 _________________
|_____|_____|_____|
|_____|     |_____|
|_____|     |_____|
```

WITHOUT ANY TRICK.. *“I think it's quite impossible with HTML alone.”*